# "Socket hang up" when trying to debug heroku nodejs from vscode

Tags: node.js, debugging, heroku, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug a heroku nodejs from vscode

My launch.json
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Heroku",
      "address": "localhost",
      "port": 9229,
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remoteRoot": "/app"
  }

My ProcFile
web: node --inspect-brk=9229 ./server.js

Already did a git push with of the ProcFile, then I run
heroku ps:forward 9229

Then I run de debug "Heroku" in VSCode, but it doesn't seem to be connecting, after some time I got the message
"Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target:socket hang up"

But if I click on stop before that message shows the forwarding process in the terminal stops, so not sure if it's connecting or not, or I still need to configure something else

Thanks

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm currently getting the exact same error.

Comment: I am getting the same error. Feb 2021. Any solution?